# Optimistic locking over multiple documents

Tags: go, couchbase, key-value-store, nosql

I need to update some documents at once, like a RDBMS transaction. The best way to do this for a single document in a key-value store like couchbase seems to be using optimistic locking. This would work for me. However, I need to update multiple documents at once.

I need all documents to be updated, or none. Is this possible in couchbase or some similar highly scalable database?

(by the way, I'm using Go)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three approaches to resolve it:

1. You should take another look at your key/document designs and identify if its possible to combine your multiple docs into one. Then you will be able to do a single transactional update in Couchbase.
2. [Simulate Transaction](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.0/#simulating-transactions) the effect can be simulated by writing a suitable document and view definition that produces the effect while still only requiring a single document update to be applied.
3. [Simulate Multi-phase Transactions](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.0/#simulating-multi-phase-transactions) to use the transaction record to record each stage of the update process

Comment: Before it might be required to record transaction stage but now we can achieve by couchbase transactions.

Comment: @Az.MaYo sure, six years later! :)

Comment: Bellow I have added transaction related answer please make vote for undelete.